# Specify Custom Keystore Provider to Android Signing Configs

Tags: android, android-app-signing

The command line version of apksigner supports the following arguments

```
--ks-provider-name <name>
--ks-provider-class <class-name>
--ks-provider-arg <value>
```

Since my company is implementing a custom keystore, I would like to use that option. But I'm wondering if there is any way for me to specify the values of those argument to the signing config block instead?

Based on the following documentation :
https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/SigningConfig
I can't seem to find the field that I need.

Actually the main goal is I want to integrate the signing process into the gradlew assemble task instead of two seperate processes (build and then sign).

Is there any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The DSL for the SigningConfig is here : https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/SigningConfig

As you can see, there is unfortunately no option to provide your own signing provider. File a feature request to the Android Gradle plugin team.